# Browser back button support

Tags: java, spring, browser

After clicking on browser back button it sends a post request and browser does not allow it to send a post request again and it displays a confirm for re submission page how to avoid this page in java with spring framework.

post request code is given below..

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "action=search_by_name")
public ModelAndView searchByName(@RequestParam("contactName") String contactName, HttpSession session, WebRequest request) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(determineSearchSummaryView(request));

    ContactSearchHelper helper = new ContactSearchHelper(contactName);

    // After all the selections they made lets filter out based on the limited Territories
    CustomerUser user = (CustomerUser) userService.getLoggedInUser();
    helper.preFilterTerritories(user.getTerritories());

    EntitySearchCriteria criteria = helper.asCriteria(searchService);
    addSummaryCounts(mav, criteria, searchService);

    Long savedSearchId = searchService.save(criteria, SavedSearchType.CONTACT, false).getId();
    helper.setSavedSearchId(savedSearchId);
    session.setAttribute(getSearchHelperParam(), helper);
    session.setAttribute("contactDiscovery", "false");
    addAccordionData(mav, null);
    addExtraModelData(mav);
    return mav;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just [need to use redirects after POSTing to some URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). You can do this with [`redirect:` prefix](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix) or with [`RedirectView`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html).

Comment: heyi madhead thanks for ur reply can u please send me the the code regarding how to redirect when click on back button .

Comment: You cannot redirect when press back button. You can send redirect (301) code after processing your POST request. And then, if you click back button no confirmation is shown.

Comment: hi madhead , this is helping me but when i search for something then it shows a result page list in thi case before rendering that result page it will redirect it to location specified ..what to do? :(

Comment: Sorry, @shitanshu, didn't got you. Is it redirecting you to wrong location?

Comment: no it is redirecting me but look at the code in  post request it returns a ModelAndView and by using this it redirects me to a URL how to set a location to  ModelAndView

Comment: `ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("redirect:/some/url");`